# If $\mathcal O_P(C)$ is a DVR, then $P$ is non-singular

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, valuation-theory

Let $C$ be an irreducible curve over $\mathbb A^2$ and $P\in C$. I would like to prove if $$\mathcal O_P(C)=\{f\in k(C)\mid f=a/b, b(P)\neq 0\}$$ is a DVR, then $P$ is non-singular, i.e., the derivatives $F_X(P)\neq 0$ or $F_Y(P)\neq 0$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I've already proved that $\dim_k(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2)=1$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_P(C)$ and $k=\mathcal O_P/\mathfrak m$. Someone could help me how to continue?

Thanks

Comment: The hope would be to reverse the argument given in your last question.

Comment: @Hoot Do you think the fact $\dim_k(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2)=1$ can give me something to solve this question?

Comment: Yes, I do. I think the picture has to be of the partial derivatives of $F$ cutting out a subspace of the tangent space $\mathbb{A}^2$. If they were both zero then you'd have something two-dimensional.

Comment: @Hoot thanks, I will keep trying to solve it. If you have some idea how to formalize this idea, please share. Thank you again!

Comment: @Hoot thank you again. I'm sorry to ask so many questions. These doubts are genuine.

Comment: I'm not doubting their authenticity! I'm doubting my ability to convey an answer that helps someone else move on. As you can see below I use like five little lemmas from abstract algebra and while I think one had better be comfortable with commutative algebra in order to study algebraic geometry, it's all a little strange if you haven't had to do this exact sort of calculation before.

Comment: Dear @Hoot I'm studying Fulton's algebraic curves book. In this level we don't need much commutative algebra. You solution below seems very basic although Fulton doesn't cover some of these concepts like cotangents and $\mathcal O_{\mathbb A^2, P}$. I think it's not your fault, there are so many ways to approach a question in Algebraic Geometry, its difficult to know what is the background of someone who is studying this field.

Comment: When I say "cotangent" below I'm just trying to be suggestive of future developments — as you can see there's nothing high-powered. But if I can attach a geometric word to something I will always do it. On the algebraic level the only observation is that these two local rings are related in some obvious algebraic way (quotienting) so if I perform some ideal-theoretic operation in one then probably it's related to performing the same operation in the other ring.

Comment: Fulton's book is, from what I've seen, very nice and complete. If I can find time later I'll try to look at his approach and see if he makes this obvious somehow. I don't think it's ever a waste of time to read something that Bill Fulton wrote.

Comment: @Hoot he proved this on page 35. His solution is very nice, the problem is I'm trying to solve this question using the same background of Fulton but without so many assumptions he made. It's a long story...

Answer (score 1):

I thought about splitting this up into a bunch of algebra exercises but decided against it. Let's just plow through it.

Let's just assume that $P = (0, 0)$, corresponding to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (x, y) \subseteq A = k[x, y]$. $C$ is cut out of $\mathbb{A}^2$ by some polynomial $f \in A$ and of course $f \in \mathfrak{m}$ if $P$ lies on $C$. The local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C, P}$ is obtained from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2, P}$ by modding out by $f$. Now, $\mathfrak{m}_{C, P} = \mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{A}^2, P}/(f)$ and $\mathfrak{m}_{C, P}^2 = (\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{A}^2, P}^2 + (f))/(f)$ and hence $\mathfrak{m}_{C, P}/\mathfrak{m}_{C, P}^2 \simeq \mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{A}^2, P}/(\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{A}^2, P}^2 + (f))$.

This is a really important point: to get the cotangent space to $C$ at $P$ you take the cotangent space to $\mathbb{A}^2$ at $P$ and quotient out by (the residue class of) the defining equation for $C$. All that (introductory, granted) algebra to make an intuitive point. One more bit of algebra: I can identify $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{A}^2,P}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{A}^2,P}^2$ with $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$. The former is the latter localized at $\mathfrak{m}$, but $A/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is already a local ring, so there's no need to localize.

Now, you can write $f$ as
$$
f(x, y) = ax + by + (\text{higher order terms})
$$
and here, really, $a = (\partial f/\partial x)(P)$ and $b = (\partial f/\partial y)(P)$. The residue class of $f$ mod $\mathfrak{m}^2$ is thus $a\bar{x} + b\bar{y}$. Here $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ form a basis for $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$. If the quotient is going to be one-dimensional then one of $a, b$ has to be nonzero.

Comment: I'm afraid I've had to repeat a lot of what's in user26857's excellent answer on the earlier question but trying to match his notation up to mine is beyond me at this hour.

Comment: I should mention that all of this generalizes to higher dimensions to show that the local ring at a point is regular if and only if the Jacobian of the defining equations has the right rank. This is done in chapter I of Hartshorne. I also want to point out that the words used in answering this question and your previous one are basically the same; one isn't really any harder than the other, it's mostly this observation that the partial derivatives come from the linear terms and that these are what cut out the (co)tangent space, and *that* is the definition of regularity.